CloudWatch Agent stops shortly after starting on AWS EC2 instance when passing Elastic Beanstalk log files
I am encountering an issue with the AWS CloudWatch Agent service on my AWS EC2 instance. After configuring the CloudWatch Agent to collect logs from Elastic Beanstalk and starting the service, it stops shortly after starting up. I've verified that the CloudWatch Agent package is installed, and the JSON configuration file seems to be correctly formatted.
I've followed the AWS documentation and configured the CloudWatch Agent JSON file (amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json) as follows:
{
  "agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "run_as_user": "root"
  },
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "/var/log/nginx/access.log",
            "log_group_name": "MyApp-Backend-Logs",
            "log_stream_name": "Development-Stream",
            "timezone": "UTC"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Despite these configurations, the CloudWatch Agent service stops shortly after starting, and I'm not sure what's causing this behavior.
Expected Behavior:
The CloudWatch Agent service should start successfully and continue running, collecting logs from the specified Elastic Beanstalk environment and sending them to CloudWatch Logs.
Actual Behavior:
The CloudWatch Agent service stops shortly after starting, and logs are not being collected or sent to CloudWatch Logs.
Here are the additional log messages I observed:
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655332]: I! imds retry client will retry 1 timesI! Detected the instance is EC2
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655332]: 2024/04/16 18:31:08 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655332]: 2024/04/16 18:31:08 I! Valid Json input schema.
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655332]: I! Detecting run_as_user...
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655332]: I! Trying to detect region from ec2
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655332]: 2024/04/16 18:31:08 Configuration validation first phase succeeded
Apr 16 18:31:08 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent[655311]: I! Detecting run_as_user...
Apr 16 18:31:15 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service - Amazon CloudWatch Agent...
Apr 16 18:31:15 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 16 18:31:15 ip-172-31-47-196.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service - Amazon CloudWatch Agent.


Could you check the logs for the cloudeatch logs agent? Is it crashing, or exiting abnormally? You should be able to find it in /var/log/awslogs.log or something similar.
